# How old was Raoul Duke in the "Fear and Loathing in Las Vegas"?

Tags: character, fear-and-loathing-in-las-vegas

The question is like in the title: how old was Raoul Duke in the "Fear and Loathing in Las Vegas"?

Comment: I don't have any supporting information, but since the character is a stand-in for Thompson himself, and it's is set in 1971, and Thompson was born in 37, that would make him about 34 at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raoul Duke is just a non prosecutable character based on the very prosecutable [Hunter S. Thompson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunter_S._Thompson) that wrote the book.

Hunter S. Thompson was born July 18, 1937, [the book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear_and_Loathing_in_Las_Vegas)..

> ..is based on two trips to Las Vegas, Nevada, that Hunter S. Thompson took with attorney and Chicano activist Oscar Zeta Acosta in **March and April 1971.**

So that would indicate he was 33 years old during the events of the book.